Are there any functions where the $2$nd derivative is the function, but the $1$st derivative isn't the function?
$e^x$ has its $1$st derivative be itself, and $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have its $4$th derivatives be itself, and not the $2$nd or $3$rd. Is there a function like this but for the $2$nd derivative?

$f(x)=Ae^{-x}$.

More generally, take the complex function $f(x) = \exp(\omega x)$, where $\omega$ is an n-th root of unity. Then $f^{(k)}(x)=\omega^k f(x) \neq f(x) $ for $0<k<n$, but $f^{(n)}(x)=\omega^nf(x)=f(x)$.
If you're uncomfortable with the function being complex, just take its real part: $f(x)=\operatorname{Re}f(x)$.
Taking $\omega=-1$ we get the answer to your question with $n=2$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}$.
Taking $\omega=\pm i$ we get things like $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, which work for $n=4$.

Equations of the form $$f(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$$ Where $A$ and $B$ are constants and $B\neq 0$ (otherwise gives a trivial solution). The first derivative will be $$f'(x)=Ae^x-Be^{-x}$$ While the second derivative will be $$f''(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}=f(x)$$ as required.

Why the condition for A!=B?

Good answer, but indeed why A not equal to B ? I see no reason ??

But you want $B \neq 0$

Sorry, yes that was quite an oversight on my part. When $A=B$, just note that $$f(x)=A(e^x+e^{-x})= 2A\cosh(x)$$Moreover, when $A$ and/or $B=0$, it does work but it gives a trivial solution (as is obvious). I'll edit my post.

One example are $\sinh$ and $\cosh$, which are sine hyperbolicus and cosine hyperbolicus:
$$
\sinh(x) = \frac{ e^x - e^{-x} }{2},
\quad 
\cosh(x) = \frac{ e^x + e^{-x} }{2},
$$
They behave similar to $\sin$ and $\cos$ but do not feature the sign change.
